# PXSelector on unbound field in PXFilter View - not showing lookup window

Tags: acumatica

Acumatica Version 19.205

I have a PXSelector attribute set on an unbound DAC field but, it's not showing the selector window when I click on the lookup icon in the field on the page.  I can start typing the inventory CD in the field and I get a drop down that tries to guess what I'm looking for but, no popup window.  I'm using the APDocumentEnq class as a reference.

Also, I'm using a PXFilter<(MyUnboundDAC)> as the view for the form.

```
    #region Item
    protected int? _Item;

    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Item")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryID),
        SubstituteKey = typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD), CacheGlobal = true)]
    public virtual int? Item {
        get
        {
            return this._Item;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Item = value;
        }
    }
    public abstract class item : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<item> { }
    #endregion
```

Here's the HTML for the lookup:

```
 <px:PXSelector CommitChanges="True" runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector54" DataField="Item" ></px:PXSelector>
```

TIA!

Comment: my guess something in the page file. Is it set as a selector field or segment field in the page (compare to another inventory id field on another page)

Comment: It shows as a "selector" in the screen designer.  I'll update my post with the HTML.

Comment: Strictly speaking the field is bound (PXDBInt) and the DAC is unbound (PXFilter). Not sure what is the issue either, I would suggest to remove all attributes on the field and just put: [Inventory(DisplayName = "Item")]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Yeah, I've bounced back and forth between PXDBInt and PXInt in order to get it to move.  I tried the [Inventory()] attribute but, I get the same.  I'm going to try removing pieces of my screen to try to narrow down where the issue is.  I'll let you know how that turns out.

Comment: oh, geez.  I found it - On the screen, I have a row with 3 columns inside of it.  The Item field is in the first column.  I had set the ColumnWidth = S on the Row but, had set the size to M on the second column.  So, the second column was actually overlaying the lookup icon for the item field.  I noticed my mouse pointer changing when I hovered.  Brendan - Thanks for pointing me to the screen.  That's indeed where the issue was.

Comment: good to hear you found the issue. Don't forget to answer your own question. You get credit and it closes out the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by adjusting the sizes on the Row and columns that contained the lookup control that was having an issue.  See comments below the original post.

The root cause was that the lookup was sitting in the first column inside of a row and the second column was over-laying the lookup icon, z-index wise:

[image: inspecting in Chrome]